# How to dynamically pass an argument to a function being called by a logic app with ethereum connector in Azure?

Tags: azure, blockchain, azure-logic-apps, azure-blockchain-service

I am using Azure blockchain Service and I made a logic app to call a function inside a smart contract whenever a particular trigger occurs.
While creating the logic app it asks me the argument with which I want to call the function. 
Now, I do not want to hard code the argument.

It is something like on my website, there are multiple products available, and whichever product the user chooses, the function should be called with the name of the product as the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here

1. HTTP triggered function and pass parameters using POST request
2. Queue triggered function and pass parameters using Azure Storage Queue

In first case you simply create HTTP trigger

[image]

Body configured as

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "product": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

This means logic app request expects JSON like this

```
{
    "product" : "abc"
}
```

This way you can use product from trigger

[image]

And use it as parameter for function call using either HTTP action

[image]

or Azure Function action

[image]

If you want to learn more about logic apps feel free to check my video intro on it https://youtu.be/ZvsOzji_8ow

If you are worried about publicly accessible webhooks for logic apps use Azure Storage Queue with Azure AD authentication or cover logic app with API management like described here https://marczak.io/posts/2019/08/secure-logic-app-with-api-management/

Comment: This makes sense.
I also realised that while using the Ethereum connector for a Logic app, the logic app is triggered whenever the ```emit event``` command is executed. And in that case, I can use the variables sent by event as parameters for the function call.
I did not try the Http Request/Response logic app. Thanks.